# Does Perl print array elements in reverse order?

Tags: perl

I am surprised the following hash array in Perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "content-type: text/html \n\n";

# DEFINE A HASH
%coins = ( "Quarter" , 25,
           "Dime" ,    10,
           "Nickel",    5 );

# LOOP THROUGH IT
while (($key, $value) = each(%coins)){
  print $key.", ".$value."<br />";
}
```

produces following output

```
Nickel, 5
Dime, 10
Quarter, 25
```

I know Perl has the ability to access last elements by indexing using negative numbers, but here we are not using negative numbers as the index so why does it print contents of hash array in reverse order?

Answer (score 11):

That's not an array, that's a hash.  Which means things are stored internally as the hash value of the key, not the order of the keys.  There is no way to get them back in the order they were added. If you want them in key order, you'll need to

```
for my $key (sort keys %coins)
{
  print $key, $coins{$key};
}
```

Comment: aa,as i understood ,first it  prints this  key which has smallest value/.

Comment: It prints them in no guaranteed or discernable order.  You can't count on any order in hashes, that's not what they're there for.

Comment: The Perl documentation for `each` say *Hash entries are returned in an apparently random order. The actual random order is subject to change in future versions of Perl.*